# References for Integrating wso2 Identity Server with SAML Authentication protocol for upgraded version of Spring boot 3.1.2 Web Application

Tags: spring-boot, wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server, spring-security-saml2

I'm building a new web Application with wso2 identity server with the Updated Spring boot Version to 3.1.2. I have to Integrate wso2 identity server with Spring Boot version from Scratch. Im in need of Documentation or any github Reference so that I can Integrated Wso2 identity server with upadated Spring boot Application. Any help is highly Appreciated.

Comment: Hi @WSO2 Team, I require SAML Authentication protocol Integration with Web Application for Spring Boot Version 3.1.2 as a Service Provider for Identity Server of wso2 6.1 Version.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in github.

https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-samples-spring-boot

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Juan Pablo, thanks for the help here, but i would like to use SAML Integration here for My Upgraded Spring Boot Version 3.1.2 Web Application